About the curvature of Riemannian surfaces
I consider a Riemannian surface $\Sigma$, an orthonormal frame $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and its dual frame $\{\omega^1, \omega^2\}$. If I denote the Levi - Civita connection as $\nabla$, I can define the $1$-form given by $\omega^1_2(e_k)=\langle \nabla_{e_k}e_2,e_1\rangle$ and moreover I know that $d\omega^1_2 = K \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2$ where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of my surface.
As I consider a Riemannian surface, I know there exist two vector fields $X, Y$ such that $\omega^1_2(X) = 0$ and $dK(Y) = 0$. Are these vector fields related in some sense? Could I express the vector field $Y$ en terms of $X$? Thank you very much in advance.

No, why do you expect a relation? First of all, when $K$ is constant, every $Y$ works. Have you worked out any examples? Edit your post to include such examples.

$\omega^1_2(X)=0$ is equivalent to $g(e_1,\nabla_Xe_2) = 0$ and therefore depends on the orthonormal frame. $dK(Y)=0$ means that $Y$ is tangent to a level set of $K$. Do you have some reason to believe that these two vector fields might be related?
